# Floating an image right and left in text box weird spacing in IE

Tags: image, internet-explorer, alignment, css-float, word-wrap

My example is [here](http://workforall.biz/workforall/success.html)

The logos look fine when told to align right or left in FF and they seem to wrap properly with the text, but in IE a huge gap shows up after the first line of text.

I have also created float right and left styles and tried to apply to the logos but got the same effect. I know this is an issue in IE, but I haven't found the fix for it yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than using the align="left" and align="right" in your HTML, just include float attributes in your floatleft and floatright CSS declarations:

```
.floatleft {
    float:left;
    padding: 0px 8px 8px 0px;
}
.floatright {
    float: right;
    padding: 0px 0px 8px 8px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! So having the alignment called out AND using the css was throwing it off huh? Actually, I didn't realize I still had the css applied to those images... I was trying two ideas but I guess I ran them together. Have a good one!